# Как создать вложенную форму для связи many to many through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

**Задача:** 
Нужно при сохранении boat создавать нового user. 
Если в user ошибка валидации то показать поля в которых есть ошибки. Если сохранение прошло успешно то показать пустую форму.

Есть три модели:

```
class Boat < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :boat_users
  has_many :users, through: :boat_users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
end

class BoatUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :boat
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :boat_users
  has_many :boats, through: :boat_users
end
```

Есть форма:

```
= form_for @boat do |f|
  ...
  = f.fields_for :users, @boat.users.build do |users|
    = f.text_field :name
  ...
```

Форма работает, но ошибки не присваиваются так экземпляр модели для формы каждый раз создается заново. Как в таком случае правильно создать форму? Пока в контроллере в ручную присваиваю ошибки и значения атрибутов, но хочется найти более красивое решение в стиле Rails Way.

Пока что мой контроллер выглядит так:

```
def update
  @user = User.new
  @boat = Boat.find(params[:id])
  @boat_user_service = BoatUserService.new

  if @boat.save
    redirect_to edit_admin_boat_path(@boat), notice: t('activerecord.models.boat.messages.success.updated')
  else
    @boat_user_service = BoatUserService.new
    @boat_user_service.assign_errors @boat.errors, @user
    @boat_user_service.assign_attributes params, @user

    render :edit
  end



end
```

И сервис вот так:

```
class BoatUserService

  def assign_attributes params, model
    model.assign_attributes params[:boat][:users_attributes].first.second
  end

  def assign_errors errors, model
    errors.messages.each do |key, message|
      array         = key.to_s.split(".")
      key_model     = array[0]
      key_attribute = array[1]

      model.errors.add(key_attribute, message) if key_model == "users"

    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, из коробки рельсы предлагают [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for).
Но решение не самое изящное. Гораздо лучше, в данном случае, использовать form_object.

```
class BoatForm
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include Virtus.model

  attribute :name, String
  attribute :user_name, String
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :user_name, presence: true

  def save
    return false unless valid?

    save_board && save_user
  end

  def persisted?
    false #это форма для нового объекта
  end

  private

  def save_board
    @board = Board.new(name: name)
    @board.save
  end

  def save_user
    @user = User.new(name: user_name)
    @user.save
    @board.users_ids << @user.id
  end

end

#controller
def new
  @form = BoardForm.new
end

def create
  @form = BoardForm.new(params[:board])
  if @form.save
    redirect_to action: :index
  else
    render action: :new
  end
end


# view
= form_for @form do |form|
  = form.text_field :name
  = form.text_field :user_name
```

В данном примере использован [Virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus) для создания атрибутов. Можно и без него.

Answer (score 0):

Возможность одной и той же вьюхи показывать **совсем свежие** экземпляры и **несохранившиеся из-за ошибок** крутится вокруг того, чтобы после `new` и `create` можно было **одними и теми же выражениями** получить их в их общей вьюхе (обычно `new`).

Простейший способ это обеспечить это instance-переменные контроллера, когда такими выражениями являются сами instance-переменные:

```
def new
  @boat = Boat.find(params[:id])
  @boat_user = @boat.users.build
end

def create
  @boat = Boat.new(boat_params)  # < С вложенными параметрами
  @bost_user = @boat.users.first # < Форма же одна?
end
```

А можно использовать выражения `@boat` и `@boat.users.first`, при условии что где-то в контроллере заполняется `@boat` и делается `@boat.users.build`.

---

<sub>Да и вообще, когда дело касается вложенных атрибутов, начинается целое ассорти из проблем, связанных с тем, что форма плохо представляет объект модели "как есть". И поэтому [эту фичу очень не любят](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/issues/959). Традиционное решение: [сделать для такой формы "формовый объект"](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/), делать в нём попытку сохранения **в транзакции**, в случае ошибок **откатывать транзакцию**, возвращать из `#save` `false` и показывать пользователю ошибки. Но это уже серьёзные изменения.</sub>