# Как узнать старое значение ассоциированной модели?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть модель **Bike** у которой есть несколько изображений через ассоциацию **has_many :pictures**

Задача: при сохранении байка, получить его старое кол-во картинок и сравнить с новым.

Я пробовал использовать такой вариант,

```
class Bike < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :old_pictures_size

  has_many :pictures, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, allow_destroy: true

  before_save do
    @old_pictures_size = pictures.size
  end

  before_update :drop_moderation

  private

  def drop_moderation
    if title_changed? || description_changed? || pictures_changed?
      self.status = :on_moderation
    end
  end

  def pictures_changed?
    @old_pictures_size > pictures.size
  end
end
```

но в переменной **@old_pictures_size** все равно новое кол-во картинок.

Comment: старое это какое? Вы при сохранении также обновляете pictures?

Comment: До сохранения картинок.

Есть форма где добавляется байк и картинки к нему через nested_forms. Пользователь может добавлять или удалять картинки у байка. Задача при сохранение байка узнать сколько было картинок до сохранения и сравнить с количеством картинок после сохранения

Comment: @PavelScheglov, на всякий случай, код контроллера тоже можно добавить в вопрос.

Comment: @PavelScheglov то есть accept_nested_attibutes для картинок у вас всё таки есть?

Comment: Могу подскаать куда копнуть, если вы обновляете также и связи (т.е. картинки) с помощью nested_attributes, попрообуйте в откатке(callback) перед записью посмотреть, набор `:pictures`, насколько я понимаю, хотя он записывается и после основной записи, но всё-таки должен быть помочен к обновлению, т.е. записи `:pictures` по идее должны быть `changed: true`. т.е это приведёт соотвественно к  `pictures_changed?: true`

Comment: @anoam код контроллера по большому счёту и не нужен =)

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ так Bike.find(1).pictures - это коллекция объектов, ну то есть у нее нет  Model::Dirty атрибутов
https://monosnap.com/file/YlltBuWeD7Z436TKDFizOLgWx38g6b.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас картинки обновляются раньше объекта сей модели, тогда просто устанавливайте надзор, если хотя бы одна запись картинки новее сей самой записи. Можно сделать что-то навроде такой проверки:

```
def pictures_changed?
   if self.new_record?
     pictures.any?
   else
     pictures.any? { |pic| pic.updated_at > self.updated_at }
   end
end
```

Comment: А как это будет работать для несохранённого объекта?

Comment: @anoam как-то так, спасибо за напоминание =)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> before_save do
>   @old_pictures_size = pictures.size
> end
> ```

Ну так значение вычисляется перед сохранением. Если до этого момента были добавлены (но не сохранены) изображения например через `bike.pictures << Picture.new)` то они уже в коллекции и посчитаются.

Самый простой (но не самый правильный) - перенести это в `after_initialize`.

Ещё хочу заметить что сравнение по количеству картинок - не самый лучший вариант проверки, были ли они добавлены. Пример: я создаю `Bike`, затем редактирую его, удаляю старую картинку и добавляю новую. Количество картинок не поменялось, но модерировать надо заново.

К тому же, коллбэки и вложенные аттрибуты очень трудно контролировать и поддерживать.
Более правильно, в данном случае, использовать `FormObject`'ы. И [Virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus) может помочь в создании таких объектов. Сделать прототип для конкретного случая не могу - слишком мало данных (нужно понимание того, что происходит в `Picture`, контроллере и каким ещё образом планируется использовать `old_pictures_size`). [Вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499370/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8-many-to-many-through/499544#499544) есть пример такого объекта для общего случая.

**UPD**

Выяснили что картинки добавляются отдельно. Вот пример `FormObject`'а:

```
class BikeForm
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include Virtus.model(constructor: false)

  attribute :id, Integer, writer: :private
  attribute :title, String
  attribute :description, String
  attribute :picture_ids, Array[Integer]
  # дефолтное значение взял с потолка. Главное чтобы не было moderation
  attribute :status, String, writer: :private, default: "confirmed"

  def initialize(bike = nil)
    set_default_attributes

    return unless bike

    self.attributes = bike.slice(:title, :description, :picture_ids)
    self.id = bike.id
  end

  # Аналогичные сеттеры можно переопределить и для других аттрибутов
  def picture_ids=(new_picture_ids)
    self.status = :moderation
    super
  end

  def save
    return false unless valid?

    bike.attributes = attributes
    bike.save
  end

  private

  def bike
    @bike ||= id ? Bike.find(id) : Bike.new
  end
end
```

Таким образом мы избавляемся от коллбэков, при изменении значащих аттрибутов объект автоматически попадёт на модерацию.

Comment: Копаясь глубже в своем коде, я обнаружил, что оказывается картинки добавляются с помощью ajax и собственного контроллера pictures c методом upload :) То есть колбеки в модели Bike вообще никак тут не помогут, т.к. пользователь может загрузить и удалить произвольное кол-во картинок не сохраняя модель байк.

Вообщем извиняю за путаницу, сейчас обновлю вопрос.

Comment: @PavelScheglov, но при сохранении формы, как минимум, сетятся новые id.
Сейчас добавлю в свой ответ пример `FormObject`'а.